# How to sum sets of random numbers in Matlab

Tags: matlab

New to Matlab programming and I would like to take 10 random numbers, sum these 10 random numbers, and I would like to do that 10 times so that I have 10 numbers which are the sums of 10 sets of 10 random numbers in each set. Sorry if that is confusing I don't know how else to word it.

I would like to use a loop and I have this code so far:

```
for i = 1:10
    a = sum(randn(10, 1));
end 
a
```

I don't really understand why this doesn't work so if someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because you overwritw the value of `a` at each iteration.

You should modify your code as follows, using `a` as an array:

```
a=[]
for i = 1:10
    a(i) = sum(randn(10, 1));
end 
a
```

Beside, you can have it done with one line only:

```
a=sum(randn(10,10))
```

This way, you generate a `10x10` array of random number, then you use directly `sum` to sum the random number `column-wise`

If you want to sum `row-wise`, you can use:

```
a=sum(randn(10,10),2)
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: That helps a lot thanks, but just for future reference, say I wanted to sum the total of the 10 numbers, would I have to take a sum of the sum of the 10?

Comment: Yes, you have: `a=sum(sum(randn(10,10),2))`.